# FFMpeg - Segment audio to chunks

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, live

I have tried [this](http://www.espend.de/artikel/iphone-ipad-ipod-http-streaming-segmenter-and-m3u8-windows.html) example in order to segment a given video file using ffmpeg into an m3u8 file and smaller chunks (.ts files). This actually worked great. Is it possible to do practically the same thing with audio input?
This was my most promising approach so far (capturing live audio on Windows OS):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="<name of input device>" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64000 | segmenter - 10 stream stream.m3u8 http://<IP_OF_SERVER>/stream/stream/ 5 1
```

But this returns this error:

```
At least one output file must be specified.
Could not open input file, make sure it is an mpegts file: -1
```

I really would not know how to convert the live audio stream to an mpegts file.
Could anyone please give me a hint?

Thanks a lot

Comment: try appending - (a dash) as the output filename to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: I added a dash just before the pipe symbol, but this just pops up a slightly different error:  
    `[NULL @ 00000000003bf8c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'pipe:: Invalid argument
Could not open input file, make sure it is an mpegts file: -1`